# How to create button using while or for in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make buttons according to the length of the arrangement.
but I don't know 
because I'm starter in flutter.

```
Widget menubar = Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                // I want make some button here button number is 10
              ],
             ),//Row
            ),//Container
           );//Center
```

Comment: Use `RaisedButton` or `FlatButton`, and wrap it with `Expanded` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i understood you completely but perhaps you could try this:

```
Widget menubar = Center(
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(10, (index) => RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Button number $index"),
        )),
      ),//Row
    ),//Container
  );//Center
```

Comment: I'm glad! Please let me know if you needed any more help. Welcome to the flutter community!